# Using .BAT files in conjunction with SQL for user input

Tags: sql, sql-server, batch-file

I have a batch file that looks like this:

```
ECHO OFF

 set /P sn= Enter Customer ID: 
 sqlcmd -S C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\Trial  -i 
  deletesql.sql -o delete.txt -v delete=%sn%
```

The database name is Trial

My **deletesql.sql** file searches through the database and deletes every record of that specific id the user inputed. For an example if the user types **1** The code should search through the database for every table that contains **CustomerID** as the column and **1** as the value.

Here's my deletesql.sql code:

```
declare @columnName nvarchar(255)
declare @intValue int
set @columnName = 'CustomerId' --COLUMN NAME WHERE VALUE IS LOCATED
set @intValue = 2              --VALUE TO BE DELETED
declare @DeleteValue varchar(10)
set @DeleteValue = convert(varchar(10), @intValue)

declare @sql nvarchar(max) = ''

select @sql =  @sql + 'delete ' + object_name(c.object_id) + ' where ' + @columnName + ' = ' + @DeleteValue + ';'
from sys.columns c 
where c.name = @columnName

select @sql

exec sp_executesql @sql
```

**The code works perfectly by its self but I am trying to get it to work in conjunction with the user input from the .bat file** As you can see I hardcoded both the column name and value in my .sql file.

**How do I change both my .sql and .bat file so that my .sql file is depending on my .bat file for an input (both column name and value)**

Also I get 3 errors in my bat file:

```
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0 : SQL Server Network Interfaces: Error Locating Server/Instance Specified [xFFFFFFFF]. .
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0 : Login timeout expired.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0 : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online..
```

Comment: Provide *absolute* paths in your batch file!

Comment: Paths containing spaces must be quoted. `sqlcmd -S "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\Trial"`